# Alternating Series approximation

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Consider the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac {(-1)^{n-1}}{3n+1}$$
>   How many terms must we sum to guarantee the approximation is correct to $3$ decimal places?

I have been stuck on this problem for quite some time now.The answers choices are $665$, $666$, $667$ or $668$. I am quite positive it is not 665.

Comment: Fun fact: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac {(-1)^{n-1}}{an+1}=\frac{\Phi \left(-1,1,1+\frac{1}{a}\right)}{a}$$ where $\Phi$ is the Hurwitz Zeta-function

Answer (score 1):

The error is smaller that the first *omitted* term.

We have $\dfrac1{3\cdot666+1}>0.0005$ and $\dfrac1{3\cdot667+1}<0.0005$.

Comment: I'm sorry I am still a bit confused.